# searching textfield for each keyword

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

Right now my views.py function allows me to search each Django textfield for the ENTIRE search phrase. However if I would like to search for a title and author, such as, "biology John", my queryset will end up empty, and I am not sure how to break up the phrase and search for individual words.

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('search')
    if query:
        results = Protocol.objects.filter(Q(title__contains=query) | Q(author__contains=query) | Q(description__contains=query) | Q(reagents__contains=query) | Q(protocol_steps__contains=query))
    else:
        results = ''
    return render(request, 'protocat_app/search_protocols.html',{'results':results})
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields there is a really small section on search fields but I'm not sure if they are relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can set up haystack with solr/elasticsearch. But if you still need some database query, you can use the following:

```
import operator

def search(request):
    terms = request.GET.get('search', '').split(' ')
    q_list = []
    for term in terms:
        if term:
            q_list.append(Q(title__contains=query))
            q_list.append(Q(author__contains=query))
            q_list.append(Q(description__contains=query))
            q_list.append(Q(reagents__contains=query))
            q_list.append(Q(protocol_steps__contains=query))

    if q_list:
        results = Protocol.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_list))
    else:
        results = ''
    return render(request, 'protocat_app/search_protocols.html',{'results':results})
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up a search server like `Solr/Elastic Search`.
Here you have just one case where you need to split the query among 2 fields. Maybe later you come up with a situation where you need to find among multiple indexed fields. Thus, `Solr` would be of great help.

You can read about Solr [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CD0QFjACahUKEwibtrTj3afHAhXKJI4KHZVXBXA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flucene.apache.org%2Fsolr%2Fquickstart.html&ei=C27NVduEN8rJuASVr5WABw&usg=AFQjCNFBv-VeOzS-rFq7TKQQSqvzm3yuCg&sig2=Na658WPJ9HCUSei3V2waeg&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E).

Also, you can make use of [django-haystack](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjABahUKEwjVl5Ov3qfHAhVRc44KHX-qALA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdjango-haystack.readthedocs.org%2F&ei=qm7NVdWaLdHmuQT_1IKACw&usg=AFQjCNHmxPT_krDRlRBnq4moRevA0KxJ4A&sig2=a2pqiHbKv903EgEpFzI3bw&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E) to make django interact with Solr and get the filtered results as per what the user searched.